# Shortest proof of the Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I was wondering about what is the shortest proof of the Chinese remainder theorem, so I can remember it for a test, and save my time. Can you help me with that?

Comment: What the “shortest proof” is depends on what knowledge/tools your have at your disposal to build on.

Comment: It also depends on your definition of CRT - of which there are various forms.

Comment: This question would be improved by adding context; what proof(s) are you aware of? Can you share the shortest proof that you know? And as suggested above; what knowledge and tools do you have at your disposal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the proof using localization is quite short, i.e. if $I_1,\dots,I_n$ are pairwise comaximal then any maximal ideal contains at most one of these ideals, hence the map $R\to R/I_1\times\dots\times R/I_n$ is surjective at the maximal ideals and therefore surjective itself.
In the case of $R=\Bbb Z$ there is also a short proof using the following argument: If $a,b$ are coprime then the map $\Bbb Z/ab\to \Bbb Z/a\times \Bbb Z/b$ is injective. As the two sets have the same number of elements it is also surjective (it also works for more that two elements).